# Delete content from vector files stored in Geopackage

Tags: qgis, geopackage

I have packaged a group of vector files (shapefiles, 30-ish) into a Geopackage database including styles, with a view to being able to use that GPKG as a standardised template with containers for future projects - to standardise layer names and default styles etc.

The individual layers still contain the entities associated with the last project from which they are archived.  The layers are a mix of point, line and polygon formats.  Is there a simple way to delete all entities within each layer within the GPKG, or do I need to open the layers within QGIS, edit (delete) and save them back to the GPKG individually?

Comment: Use SQL `DELETE FROM your_table;` and then `VACUUM;`.

Comment: Ogrinfo can be used for that ogrinfo -sql "delete from your_table" your_geopackage.gpkg. It may be better to close all the layers which are opened from that GeoPackage into QGIS first. Otherwise changes go into write ahead log (.wal file) to wait until all connections are closed.