# Deleting entries (duplicates) from a GPKG using OGR

Tags: sql, ogr2ogr, geopackage, delete

I tried to delete duplicates from a GPKG file using `ogr2ogr` and a [SQLite statement from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25885564/9778755):

```bsh
ogr2ogr -sql "DELETE FROM layer WHERE rowid NOT IN (SELECT MIN(rowid) FROM layer GROUP BY column_with_duplicates)" unique.gpkg duplicates.gpkg
```

Unfortunately there is an error: `attempt to write a readonly database`

Answer (score 3):

[This comment](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/362441/delete-content-from-vector-files-stored-in-geopackage#comment593063_362441) made me aware that `ogr2ogr` cannot be used to delete entries from a GPKG. We must use `ogrinfo`:

```bsh
ogrinfo -sql "DELETE FROM layer WHERE rowid NOT IN (SELECT MIN(rowid) FROM layer GROUP BY column_with_duplicates)" duplicates.gpkg
```

Then rename the result:

```bsh
mv duplicates.gpkg unique.gpkg
```

Comment: Wow, this is some new use of `ogrinfo` I have not seen before. I haven't been able to make it work for my particular case. Figured out another method based on this, added it as a separate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Sticking with [`ogr2ogr`](https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html), one can do:

```
ogr2ogr -sql "SELECT * FROM layer WHERE rowid IN (SELECT MIN(rowid) FROM layer GROUP BY column_with_duplicates)" \
        -dialect sqlite \
        out.gpkg in.gpkg \
        -nln newLayerName
```

Then you can `mv out.gpkg in.gpkg`, if you are happy with the result.